# Call specific element of Javascript Array object

Tags: javascript, serialization

I have a page with many forms, all the same. A single form is submitted at once and the fields are serialized into an array. How do I access the specific values of the array?

forms on page, each with a unique ID:

````
```    <form  id="411-FORM">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="411" />
                <input type="radio" id="Radio-411" name="Radio" value="Agree">
                <label for="Agree">Agree</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="RadioD-411" name="Radio" value="Disagree">
                <label for="Disagree">Disagree</label><br>
                <textarea class="form-control"  name="rebutText" placeholder="Details" id="txt-411"> 
    </textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="btn_click('411');" value="Save Rebuttal" class="btn btn-primary" 
     currentID="411-DIV"/>
      </form>
```
````

function accepting the form:

````
```
    function btn_click(divID) {
                console.log("form submitted22!")
                //alert(divID);
                

                divID = "#" + divID
     
             
                alert(divID);
                
                let textVal = divID + "-FORM";
                console.log($(textVal).serializeArray());

                let formArray = $(textVal).serializeArray();
                
                console.log(formArray.values);

//Right here is where I want to obtain a specific element in the form, by name, not by index

                }

 ```
````

the result in the console is this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "id", value: "411"}
1: {name: "Radio", value: "Agree"}
2: {name: "rebutText", value: ""}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

how do I print or obtain the single radio value?

I've tried:
formArray[Name="Radio"]
formArray[1]["Name"]- will return Radio, but not the value and the array isn't always placing the radio value at this index
formArray.Radio.Value - error?

Nothing online shows me specifically how to call elements from this, since the forms are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.filter`, and give it a boolean criteria to return the value you're looking for from anywhere in the list:

`formArray.filter(f => f.name=="Radio")`

Edit: If you just want to print or return the `value`,

```
let result = formArray.filter(f => f.name=="Radio")
console.log(result.value)
return result.value
```

(Edit: this will return multiple results if there are multiple "Radio"s in your array, if you just want the first one in the array, `.find` is a good solution as others have suggested; either way if there are multiple "Radio"s you might have to expand your criteria for either `.filter` or `.find` to get what you're looking for, eg, `f.name=="Radio" && f.value=="Agree"`)

Comment: this results in {name: "Radio", value: "Disagree"}, I am trying to access the value within this pair now. I apologize, I am not familiar with Javascript and continue to attempt to access the value of the name, which would be "Agree" or "Disagree"

Comment: So you just need the value?

Comment: yes, just the value. Trying what was offered in another answer using {.value}, does not work.

Comment: this oddly doesn't work with result.value, but does with result[0]['value']

Comment: My bad, `filter` returns an array with the results (which you might want, again, if you have multiple radio buttons). `.find` will return the first object that fits the criteria. Here's an example: https://repl.it/repls/JubilantPresentArchives#index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (see the first example there, it is exactly your case)

```js
formArray.find(e => e.name==="Radio")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to iterate over the array and the properties of its elements.  Each array element/object has two properties, `name` and `value`.  You access them using standard objection property notation.  eg. `formArray[0]['value']` will give you `411`.

Here are some iteration examples that should help you understand the composition of your array.

```js
const formArray = [
  {name: "id", value: "411"},
  {name: "Radio", value: "Agree"},
  {name: "rebutText", value: ""},
]

// forEach, using dot notation
formArray.forEach( el => {
  console.log("el:", el)
  console.log("name:", el.name)
  console.log("value:", el.value)
})

// indexing, and using bracket notation
for( let i=0; i < formArray.length-1; i++ ) {
  console.log( formArray[i]['name'])
  console.log( formArray[i]['value'] )
}
```

To get the `value` of an element whose `name` matches a particular string, you could use the built in `find` method on arrays, then access the returned element to get the value.

eg.

```js
const found = formArray.find( el => el.name == 'Radio' )
if( found ) {
  console.log( found.value ) // "Agree"
} else {
  // no element with name: "Radio" was found in the array
}
```